# Xamarin.Forms dynamically change Master page content

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have a simple app with Master-Detail page.

It looks similar:
[image]

And I want to dynamically change Master page content.
E.g. on Detail page there are some Button and then you click on it - some items from Master page dissapear.

I've tried to find some item properties like `item1.isVisible=False` but found nothing.

Is there any way I can do it?

`MainPage` code:

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        masterPage.listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
    }

    void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
            masterPage.listView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```

`MainPage` XAML:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns=....>
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:SomePage/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

`MasterPage` XAML:

```
    <StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="10,50,0,0">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:MasterPageItem}">
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="Home" TargetType="{x:Type views:HomePage}" IconSource="nav_icon_home"/>
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="Settings" TargetType="{x:Type views:HomePage}" IconSource="nav_icon_settings" />
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="My Profile" TargetType="{x:Type views:HomePage}" IconSource="nav_icon_profile" />
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="Help" TargetType="{x:Type views:HomePage}" IconSource="nav_icon_help" />
                <local:MasterPageItem Title="About" TargetType="{x:Type views:AboutPage}" IconSource="nav_icon_about"/>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="10,10,10,10" ColumnSpacing="10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

`MasterPage` items:

```
public class MasterPageItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string IconSource { get; set; }

    public Type TargetType { get; set; }
}
```

So I've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` inside `MasterPageItem`:

```
public class MasterPageItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string IconSource { get; set; }

    public Type TargetType { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    private bool isVisible;

    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return isVisible; }
        set
        {
            isVisible = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsVisible"));
        }
    }

}
```

But how can I bind this to my `MasterPage`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I've implemented 2 different `MasterPages`, so I can switch between them when needed.

So I have 2 `MainPages` the 1st one refers to `MasterPage1`:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MasterPage1 x:Name="masterPage1" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
<NavigationPage>
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:SomePage1/>
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

The 2nd `MainPage2` - to `MasterPage2`:

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MasterPage2 x:Name="masterPage2" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>

<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
<NavigationPage>
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:SomePage2/>
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

I know it's not the best solution, but for my case it's enough.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you can change the View of the Master Page by changing the `Master`-Property of a `Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage`. If you assigned a `Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage` to the `Master`-Property, you can acces it by `((ContentPage)YourMasterDetailPage.Master).Content`.

Im sure this question has been answered already 100 times and follows the basic structure of xamarin forms.

Learn MasterDetailPage from scratch here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page

Since you provided some code now, here's a little example:

```
void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
            item.IsVisible = false; //this would make the clicked item invisible
            masterPage.listView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code. There are no 100 similar questions (or maybe I'm blind and can't see them), it's a lot of explanations about Detail's page structure, but very few about Master's.

Comment: `MasterPageItem` is the bindable object inside a List? This List is bound to masterPage.listView.ItemsSource? There is no difference between Detail and Master page. Both are expected to be of a type derived of `Xamarin.Forms.Page`

Comment: Could you please expand your answer somehow?

Comment: you have to show me where and how you are setting the listview ItemsSource. but i can assume you bind a list to it. Add a bool "IsVisible" to the `MasterPageItem` and bind it to the IsVisible property of the viewcell tenplate of your listview. I hope your masterpageitem implements INPC, if not, you have to research on that.

Comment: I've added `MasterPageItem` and `MasterPage` XAML code. 

Also I've tried to implement `INPC`, could you please tell me if I'm doing it right and how can I bind it to the viewcell?

Comment: Try adding "IsVisible={Binding IsVisible}" to the grid of the ViewCell template (line 15 of MasterPage XAML). Then whenever you change the property on the specific masterpageitem this should toggle the visibility. (Since bool default value is "false" your items should be invisible right now)

Comment: It's worked fine, elements are invisible now. But I don't understand - how can I change visibility for individual items? Since I've created them inside XAML. Should they have some `ID` or what?

Comment: I mean, of course I can add `IsVisible` to individual items inside XAML, but how can I set it from `cs` code?

Comment: If you change the value of the MasterPageItem, the Binding of IsVisible will propagate the change to the view. I added some lines of yours and added one line with a comment.

Comment: It's clear now, thank you. But in the end, I decided to just make 2 different `MasterPages`. So I can switch between then needed.